# Socket programming - setsockopt: Protocol not available?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming, setsockopt

I'm doing some basic socket programming in C and I'm running into this error on every computer I try to run the code on. The code compiles fine, but when I try to run it I get the error setsockopt: Protocol not available. It doesn't seem to be a very common error, yet I'm having it with every computer I try to run it on. All of the computers have been MacOS.

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 8080 
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in address; 
    int opt = 1; 
    int addrlen = sizeof(address); 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    char *hello = "Hello from server"; 

    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) 
    { 
        perror("socket failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, 
                                                  &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
    { 
        perror("setsockopt"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT ); 

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                                 sizeof(address))<0) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) 
    { 
        perror("listen"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                       (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) 
    { 
        perror("accept"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024); 
    printf("%s\n",buffer ); 
    send(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 ); 
    printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I was told that I needed to include the setsockopt() method so that processes that restart can connect to the address without being blocked because of waiting time after the tcp connection shuts down. Anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: You can't combine socket options with `|`, they're not bit masks.

Comment: You need to call `setsockopt()` twice, once for `SO_REUSEADDR` and then for `SO_REUSEPORT`.

Comment: In fact you only need to set `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/how-do-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-differ

Comment: Thanks so much, I put SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT into different setsockopt() methods and now it works fine.

Answer (score 28):

I had a similar problem just replace this piece of code

```
// Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt)))
```

with this

```
// Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR , &opt, sizeof(opt)))
```

this worked (on macOS) for me fine.